# Joint Probability - Random Sample

Tags: probability

At a sandwich stall, the following statements are true:

- $40\%$ of customers bought a packet of crisps
- Of the customers who bought crisps, $10\%$ also bought a bar of chocolate.

1. Let $C$ denote the event of a customer buying a packet of crisps, and $S$ denote the event of a customer buying a bar of chocolate. 
   Calculate the probability that a randomly chosen customer buys a packet of crisps and a bar of chocolate.
   I've worked out $P(C \ \cap \ S) = P(C) \cdot P(C|S) =0.40\cdot0.10 = 0.04$
2. Additional info is now given that $25\%$ of customers buy a bar of chocolate. Calculate the probability that a randomly chosen customer who buys chocolate also buys crisps.
3. What percentage of customers buy a bar of chocolate or a packet of crisps or both.

Not really sure where to start on 2. and 3.?

Answer (score 1):

1. You've made a typo:  $P(C \cap S) = P(C) P(S \mid C) =0.40 \times 0.10 = 0.04$.
2. $P(S) = 0.25$, so $P(S \mid C) = \dfrac{P(C \cap S)}{P(C)} = \dfrac{0.04}{0.40} = 0.1$
3. $P(C \cup S) = P(C) + P(S) - P(C \cap S) = 0.40 + 0.1 - 0.04 = 0.46$